# xpath and java if no id is matched

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a list of words from using a tokenizer which all have a number reference to them i.e.: Rottweiler = n#10001

I also have an xml file which I can use to find that Rottweiler is category dog.

Some of these words however have an id that isnt in the xml file,  What I want to do is have my program move onto the next one if the id doesn’t match any id in the xml file. Right now my whole program just breaks if it doesn’t find it.

this is what i have so far:

```
String search1 = "11111";
String nodePrefix =  "n#"+search1;

Node theNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@id='" + nodePrefix+"']", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
String categ = theNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("categ").getNodeValue();
System.out.println("Animal "+ nodePrefix + " has category " + categ);
        ...more code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If expression:

```
Node theNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@id='" + nodePrefix+"']", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

does not find a node, it returns `null`. So you can't do anything in this case and you should avoid execution of the rest of program.

```
Node theNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@id='" + nodePrefix+"']", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
if(theNode!=null){
    String categ = theNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("categ").getNodeValue();
    System.out.println("Animal "+ nodePrefix + " has category " + categ);
            ...more code
}
```

There are also another flow control statements like `break`, `return` or even labels that you can use to avoid this pitfall.

Comment: in that case could i use an if statement to say if the node is notnull run the rest?

Comment: This is exactly what theNode!=null means. If node is not null rub the rest of code.